# Flask use the same blueprint across files

Tags: python, flask

this is my project structure:

```
- app.py
- views/
    - admin/
        - __init__.py
        - note.py
        - album.py
```

in `views/admin/__init__.py` I created a blueprint:

`admin_bp = Blueprint('admin_bp', __name__, url_prefix='/admin')`

and I'd like to use this blueprint in both `note.py` and `album.py`

what I've tried:

```
# note.py

from views.admin import admin_bp

@admin_bp.route('/note/list')
def list_notes():
    pass
```

But it seems that the url rule is not generated at all

thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Are you loading the blueprint in app.py?

```
from admin import admin_bp
app.register_blueprint(admin_bp)
```

Ensure that you are importing `note.py` & `album.py` inside `admin/__init__.py`.

This should then load the URLs.

If that fails it may be worth printing the contents of the URL map:

```
print app.url_map
```

Regards

Comment: Yeah, of course I registered the blueprint in app.py, but it doesn't work...and I've checked `app.url_map`, and the urls are not there

Comment: Are you importing `note.py` and `album.py`in `__init__.py`?

Comment: won't that cause circular import?

Comment: No. As it stands the note.py and album.py are not being seen by the interpreter so the functions are never registered with the blueprint